# Javascript regex positive look behind

Tags: javascript

Given the string: `x = 'it is 2.5i in'`
what is wrong with this code `x.replace(/(?<=\d+\.\d+)i/gi,'')`
 so that the outcome is "it is 2.5 in"?

The code gives a console error on chrome.

> Invalid regular expression: /(?<=\d+.\d+)i/:

That is, the code needs to use regex to remove the letter "i" only if it is after a digit followed by a dot followed by a digit. thx

Comment: JavaScript doesn't support lookbehind expressions, hence an error.

Comment: What other ways to solve this then? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use capture:

```
x = 'it is 2.5i in';
x = x.replace(/(\d+\.\d+)i/gi,'$1');
console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for this:

```
x.replace(/(\d+\.\d+)i/gi,'$1')
```

Comment: You omit the capture braces.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following regex to remove the letter "i" only if it is after a digit followed by a dot followed by a digit.

```
var x  = 'it is 2.5i in'; 
var y = x.replace(/(\d+)(.)(\d+)(i)/, "$1$2$3");
```

$1, $2 and $3 refers to the groups. $1 matches number before the decimal; $2 gives matches the decimal itself;$3 matches the number following the decimal and 
$4 matches the character i.

When replacing I've omitted $4 and hence removed 'i'